# Effect on SEO of lazy scrolling on HTML comments

Tags: seo, html, jquery, page-speed, load-time

I am thinking about using a JS script that lazy loads HTML when scrolling ( http://ivorycity.com/blog/2011/04/19/jquery-lazy-loader-load-html-and-images-on-scroll/).

I am not too sure about whether this approach is SEO friendly. As far as I know, search enginges ignore text within comments. Even worse, the site might get degraded because of so many comments. How should I handle this requirement? Are there any alternative approaches?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since November 2011 The Googlebot has been able to read [AJAX/javascript content](http://fisheye-webdesign.co.uk/blog/google-can-now-read-comments-in-javascript-and-ajax/), facebook, [Google+ and twitter](http://www.jefftk.com/news/2012-01-11.html) content etc. Since Matt Cutts [specifically mentioned comments](https://twitter.com/#!/mattcutts/status/131425949597179904) in his tweet I believe your content will get indexed.

> Matt Cutts of Google Tweeted yesterday that ***“Google can now execute
>   AJAX/JavaScript to index some dynamic comments.”*** which means its web
>   crawlers can now ‘read’ some dynamically generated content previously
>   hidden. Exactly how much of this content is unclear. However, he does
>   specifically mention the word **comments** rather than all
>   Ajax/JavaScript. This is still fantastic news for our developers who
>   love nothing more than to include complex functionality into their web
>   design whilst maintaining search engine friendliness.

Since Google is also indexing [Facebook and Twitter comments](http://blog.optimum7.com/safon/google/google-now-indexing-fb-comments.html) and I notice comments on the envato network turn up frequently in search results I don't believe you'll be penalised for having too many comments. But the article I linked to above does state:-

> With Google crawling and indexing comments, **moderation will become
>   more important than ever**. Website owners and administrators should pay
>   close attention to their comment sections to ensure they aren’t in
>   violation of [Google’s Webmaster Guidelines](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=35769#3). **Too many comments left for
>   trolling and spamming purposes** will result in a negative PageRank,
>   while hate speech could result in blacklisting.

So best to have a read and keep a close eye on what people are saying on your site.

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive answer. Very good to know about this! Unfortunately I was not talking about comments as a reaction to an article. But comments as in commenting HTML code in order to hide it from the browser.

Comment: @marlene For the same reasons that I address above you should be fine, google is capable of distingushing excessive commenting from code with comments. Take a look a my answer to this question, which addresses your situation more closely http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/27060/do-search-engines-see-comments-in-the-source-code-as-a-backlink